# Filtrar una lista con mas de 5000 registros

Tags: jquery, html5

Hola que tal hoy vengo a pedirles su ayuda, la cuestión es que tengo que filtrar una lista con mas 5000 registros, lo malo es que al momento de ingresar texto este tarda mucho o en el peor de los casos se bloquea.
Mi código es el siguiente.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<h2>Tutorials</h2>
<input class="form-control" id="demo" type="text" placeholder="Search here...">
<br>
<ul class = "list-group" id = "newList">
<?php
include("conexion.php");

$consulta = $con -> query ("SELECT serie FROM usuarios");

if ($consulta ->num_rows != 0)
 {
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
       echo "<option>".$consulta["serie"]."</option";
      }
 }

?>
</ul>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo").on("keyup", function() {
           var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
           $("#newList li").filter(function() {
              $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
           });
        });
     });
  </script>

<body>
<htm>
```

Les agradeceria bastante su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría en tu caso, es hacer paginación y hacer el filtro con una consulta mysql, porque por muy buen filtro que hagas, si a la BD sigue creciendo tarde o temprano no podrás traerte toda la BD entera a una pagina.

Comment: Creo que asi sera, ya que aun no me queda. muchas gracias